# how its better to filtering a file by using awk with more than two pattern matching?

Tags: awk, filter, vcf-variant-call-format

I want to modify this command and create a command to filter rows with "val" flag and more than 2 "PASS".
any suggestion?

this command can work only with one PASS:

`awk '{if(($5=="val") && ($0 ~ /PASS/ )) {print $0}}' sample.vcf`

Comment: please update the question to show sample input (preferably with a sample that matches your requirement, and a sample that does *not* match your requirement) and the expected output; also consider reviewing [how do I format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and update the question accordingly

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Your example awk line is equivalent to `awk '$5=="val" && /PASS/' sample.vcf`, no need for `if`, any parenthesis, action block, nor print statement. A *pattern* (in this case with two components joined with `&&`) prints the line ($0) by default if the pattern is found in that line.

Comment: @DavePritlove: and `/PASS.*PASS/` matches two occurrences of "PASS". Or for more than two: `.*(PASS.*){3,}.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $5 is the flag field:

`awk '{if(($5=="val") && ($0 ~ /^.*PASS.*PASS.*$/ )) {print $0}}' sample.vcf`

BTW `{if(($5=="val") && ($0 ~ /PASS/ )) {print $0}}` will not match any lines since `if $5 == "val" $0` will never `~ /PASS/`

Comment: Thank you Dennis. its good and work now. would you please tell me whats the meaning of "^" and "*$" means in the command? thank you

Comment: "^" matches start of line; "." matches any char and "*" matches any number of preceding char, so ".*" will match anything (including nothing); $ matches end of line